# How to use Deferred Deep Linking in facebook sdk of React Native?

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I have created Deferred Deep Links but how can I use this in React native as I have not seen anything related to deep link in FBSDK.
Can React native's  Linking.getInitialURL() can handle Deferred Deep Links after installation from play store?

Comment: Did you get this thing to work? If so could you explain how damn thing works.